# В українській мові можна використовувати присудок «є»?

Tags: вживання-слів, калька

В українській мові можна використовувати присудок «є»? Наприклад: «Проект є унікальним втіленням технічної ідеї». Деякі посібники, зокрема "Українська мова у професійному спілкуванні" Ірини Левчук вказують на те, що подібні речення – калькування з польської.  Проте, речення так все ж будують. То як краще?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання містило контекст. Окрім того, запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на запитання, не заохочують інших до того, щоб надавати відповіді.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити запитання, для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: В питанні є контекст і воно відповідає правилам.

Comment: Якщо ж Вас влаштовують відповіді і Ви їх приймаєте, ставте, будь ласка, прапорець "✔". Таким чином збільшується рейтинг. Дякую за розуміння!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, іноді такий присудок використовують. Проте дієслово-зв'язка "бути" у формі теперішнього часу ("**є**"), як правило, опускається. Присудок із пропущеною дієслівною зв'язкою вважається складеним іменним із нульовою зв'язкою. Наприклад:

> Паляниця - хлібові сестриця.

Таку інформацію знаходимо у [Гіпермаркеті знань](http://edufuture.biz/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Зв'язка **"є"** (або застаріла форма **"єсть"**) вживається лише в окремих випадках для надання висловлюванню офіційності чи урочистості. Наприклад:

> Я єсть народ, якого правди сила ніким звойована ще не була (Тичина.)
>
> Найвищим законом держави є її Конституція.

Інформація взята із сайту [«Школа сучасних знань»](http://www.zhu.edu.ua/mk_school/mod/page/view.php?id=1640).